# Adding a Video from our server but not working in IE9

Tags: video, internet-explorer-9

I have added a video from the server but the video works in everywhere except IE9

Can someone help me. here is the code

```
<video width="420" height="240" controls="" tabindex="0">

           <source type="video/ogg" src="/images/towable_shelters.ogv"></source>
            <source type="video/mp4" src="/images/towable-shelters.mp4"></source>
            <source type="video/wmv" src="/images/towable_shelters.wmv"></source>
                 <object width="420" height="240" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="FlashID">
              <param value="/images/towable_shelters.swf" name="movie">
              <param value="high" name="quality">
              <param value="opaque" name="wmode">
              <param value="11.0.0.0" name="swfversion">
              <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
              <param value="/images/expressInstall.swf" name="expressinstall">
              <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
              <!--[if !IE]>-->
              <object width="422" height="240" data="/images/towable_shelters.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
                <!--<![endif]-->
                <param value="high" name="quality">
                <param value="opaque" name="wmode">
                <param value="11.0.0.0" name="swfversion">
                <param value="/images/expressInstall.swf" name="expressinstall">
                <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
                <div>
                  <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
                  <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img width="112" height="33" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif"></a></p>
                </div>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
              </object>
              <!--<![endif]-->
          </object>
        </video>
```

This works perfectly in all the browsers. even IE6 and IE7 as it takes the swf to work. But I have no clue why its not working in IE9